# Creating form and connection to the database but doesn't work

Tags: php, forms, mysqli, database-connection

I have several question and I hope there is answer that makes it true!
I'm very beginner in PHP but I like challenging with codes! I created a form like below in "test.html" file:

```
<form method="post" action="process.php">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-push-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>name</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>family</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="family">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-pull-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>email</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>phone</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="phone" name="phone">
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <label>choose one of the options</label>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="order" value="box1"> box1
                <input type="radio" name="order" value="box2"> box2
                <input type="radio" name="order" value="box3" checked> box3
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <input class="btn btn-primary btn-xs btn-block" value="send" style="color:#fff;" type="submit" name="submit" />
    </div>
</form>
```

and then I created a PHP code to give data from users and send it to database like below:

```
<?php
$connect=mysqli_connect('server_name','database_username','password','database_name');
if(mysqli_connect_errno($connect))
  {echo 'Failed to connect';}
$name = $_POST['name'];
$family = $_POST['family']; 
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$order = $_POST['order'];
mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO table_name(name,family,email,phone,order)
  values('$name','$family','$email','$phone','$order')");
if(mysqli_affected_rows($connect)>0)
  {echo '<p>sent!</p>'echo '<a href="test.html">GO BACK</a>';}
else
  {echo 'it's failed.';echo 'mysqli_error($connect)';} ?>
```

And my table that I created is :

```
create a table with id => int unsigned auto-increment primary and name,
 family and email => varchar(50) latin1_swedinsh_ci and 
 phone => int(20) and 
 order => varchar(20)  latin1_swedinsh_ci
```

My questions are :

1. is my ip address equal to ip:2082 ? or domain:2082? or it's wrong!?
2. my username and password of database that i set in my php code is quite easy to hacked! is any way to solve this? i guess that my pirivilage is my answer!
3. I set ip:2082 and filled out my form and click submit button and either say "sent" nor "it's failed!"... I think it's connected but didn't insert my data into table!

Comment: downvoted because: 
1. The html code is useless unless you understand arabic.
2. The php code is not formatted and is in one line.
3. The description of the table is not formatted.
4. The list of question are basic and should be solved studying php.

Comment: where 2082 come from?

Comment: it's path to enter in cpanel, for example : http://domain.com:2082 is cpanel path

Answer (score 0):

1. 2082 is not related to your ip address, is the web server port. By default is 80, and you can just ignore, but sometime is different and this is why you need to specify on the url.
2. Password are stored on php file because php files are stored on your server and user cannot have access to them.